# Is Select a DML or DDL?

Tags: mysql, sql, netezza

I was going through DML SQL statement. Select as they say is a SQL data statement and these are also called as DML.

most of the articles explain it with below eg:
If select is used as below then it is classified as DML

```
Select COl1, COl2 
into Table2 #this -- part will create a table named
                  -- as table2 with column col1 and col2
from Table1;      -- 3 columns will be copied from table1 to table2
```

1) Can somebody Please explain what is exactly happening in the query

```
Select COL1, Col2
into TABLE2
from TABLE1;
```

2) How is this a DML statement?

3) Is there is any difference between SQL data statement and DML or both are same ? http://www.firstsql.com/tutor1.htm

Comment: Data Manipulation Language (DML) is a vocabulary used to **retrieve** and work with data. Use these statements to add, modify, **query**, or remove data from a database.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html

Comment: `DDL` works with the database structure. `DML` works with the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Inserting data that is selected from TABLE1 to TABLE 2
2. It *is* data manipulation
3. From the look of it they are the same

EDIT:
To answer the question title as well, `SELECT` is not a DDL (Data definition language). DDL statements modify database layout, like `CREATE TABLE`. DML statements are queries data, like `SELECT`; or modifies data, like `INSERT`.

Another edit:
It seems `SELECT INTO` is not fully supported in mysql. Even though answer is still valid for general SQL. For me, `SELECT INTO`'s table creation aspect is a side effect. thus it is still a DML.

Comment: so Select col1, col2 into table2 from table1 will create a new table or will it insert the data in some columns in table 2 from table 1 , if yes then which column in table 2?

Comment: @VivekRana: they are ordered, but its best to use `INSERT TO ... SELECT` syntax, this way you can specify which columns to affect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can correctly view it as a hybrid that accomplishes both data manipulation (selecting and inserting) and definition (table creation). I don't think you'll find `SELECT...INTO` in the standard language which is one reason you probably can't apply a strict distinction between DML and DDL here.